# PHP - Access-Control-Allow-Origin not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, cors

I own a site that we'll call www.example.com. The main chunk of my site is in two files; header.php and index.php. The top half of the website code is in header.php while the bottom half is in index.php. My problem is, I can't get the Access-Control-Allow-Origin attribute to show up in the response header from example.com

**My code:**
The following is a simplified version of header.php:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*", false);
...
additional code here
...
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Site</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        ....
        top half of site code
        ....
```

The following is a simplified version of index.php:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*", false);
include ("header.php");
?>
        ....
        bottom half of site code
        ....
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is my request to retrieve the images:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url : folder,
            success: function (data) {
                if($(".img").length){
                    $(".img").remove();
                }

                $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
                    if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) {
                        $("#img-lib").append( "<img class='img' src='"+ folder + val +"'>" );
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                $("#er").remove();
                $("#img-lib").append("<p id='er'>There was an error retrieving the images</p>");
            }
});
```

**My error:** This is what I get when I try to access www.example.com/Section/images/ :
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/29t8n.jpg 


**What I have already tried:**
(The following code snippets are the first line of php code)

- `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");` in header.php ONLY.
- `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:www.example.com");` in header.php ONLY.
- `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");` in header.php and index.php
- `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*", false);` in header.php and index.php

It Might be worth mentioning that the site I am currently building is going to be used to edit my existing site (www.example.com).

Comment: Does it work with *? Have you forced refresh of the page?

Comment: @DanielKucal It doesn't work with *. I have refreshed the page I'm building and example.com but still not working.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem — https://www.evernote.com/l/AANksxHmPBlG4qXVPoY3b-ZUH4Dz6kXo9Xo — Possibly you have some other code before the header statement that is causing an error to be thrown, possibly you made an error in the deployment.

Comment: "I'm not sure if this will help but here is the headers I get when I try to retrieve the files from images/" — The URL shown in that screenshot is showing the standard directory listing from Apache. That doesn't appear to be the PHP program you said you were using.

Comment: @Quentin There is no image in the comment above ^. I have rewritten the majority of my question to be more specific.

Comment: @CodyCook - http://i.stack.imgur.com/29t8n.jpg  is an image, in the image is some text, that text includes the URL you are accessing, that URL points to the aforementioned Apache directory listing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably your static files, like images, aren't accessed via index.php (you are referring to their physical location). In this case, CORS headers can be set at the level of HTTP server. If it handles .htaccess files, you can simply create `.htaccess` file containing following content:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
```

in the main or specified directory.

Comment: `https://www.example.com/Section/images/` doesn't look like the URL to a static file.

Comment: You can not exclude that option. In other case it can be dynamic, but does not go through the index.php file.

Comment: @DanielKucal I feel silly for overlooking this answer yesterday but this did the trick. One thing I would recommend, for anyone else running an apache server, follow this article http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin attribute to the config file.